# Running PowerShell script that leverages Parameter Sets without any parameters

Tags: powershell

How do I allow the option to run a PowerShell script that leverages parameter sets to run without passing any parameters? Is this possible?

```
param(

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="GenSecureFile used to generate secure password file.",     ParameterSetName = 'GenSecureFile')]
  [switch]$GenSecureFile,

  [Parameter(Mandatory=$true,HelpMessage="GenSettingsFile used to generate settings file.", ParameterSetName = 'GenSettingsFile')]
  [switch]$GenSettingsFile

)
```

Attempted to use a default parameter but this does not let you run the script with no parameters.

Comment: This is possible but looking at your `param` block you have 2 `switch` parameters in different sets and these are the only 2 parameters. This leads be to believe your `param` should be reduced to only 1 `[string]` parameter that uses a `[ValidateSet(...)]` attribute decoration

Answer (score 2):

For this to work properly the parameter being declared as [`DefaultParameterSetName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_cmdletbindingattribute?view=powershell-7.3#defaultparametersetname) shouldn't be flagged as `Mandatory` and possibly **be set to `$true` which wouldn't make sense for a `switch` Parameter**. [**`switch` Parameters are meant to be optional (should not be `Mandatory`) and should not have a default value.**](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_functions_advanced_parameters?view=powershell-7.3#switch-parameter-design-considerations)

For Example:

```
function Test-Parameter {
    [CmdletBinding(DefaultParameterSetName = 'GenSecureFile')]
    param(
        [Parameter(ParameterSetName = 'GenSecureFile')]
        [switch] $GenSecureFile = $true,

        [Parameter(Mandatory, ParameterSetName = 'GenSettingsFile')]
        [switch] $GenSettingsFile
    )

    end {
        $PSCmdlet.ParameterSetName
    }
}

Test-Parameter
```

What you should do instead is have only **one parameter that uses a [`ValidateSet` Attribute Declaration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/developer/cmdlet/validateset-attribute-declaration?view=powershell-7.3)**, by doing so there wouldn't be a need for Parameter Sets.

For Example:

```
function Test-Parameter {
    [CmdletBinding()]
    param(
        [Parameter()]
        [ValidateSet('SecureFile', 'SettingsFile')]
        [string] $Gen = 'SecureFile'
    )

    end {
        if($Gen -eq 'SecureFile') {
            # do something here when `SecureFile`
            return
        }

        # do something here when `SettingsFile`
    }
}

Test-Parameter
```

Comment: it would seem to me that the END block is un-necessary? Is there something I'm missing?

Comment: @RetiredGeek It is un-necessary but also a preference. I like to be explicit. You're correct tho, a function or scriptblock with undeclared blocks assumes `end`